# Horizontal dragging of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a subclass of `UIScrollView` class and this scroll have vertical content. But I need drag and drop this `UIScrollView` in the parent view on horizontal direction. How can I implement this?

Comment: What's in the scroll view? Custom views or built-in ones? If the latter, are they `UIControl`s?

Comment: UIscrollView has few subviews aligned vertically.

Comment: iOS doesn't natively do dragging — but if they're `UIControl`s then it's a lot easier to add than if they're just `UIView`s. So are they custom or built in? If they're built in, do they subclass from control?

Comment: What I need to subclass? I don't understand, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a specific hierarchy:

Before you do anything you must go to your StoryBored and deselect the Autolayout option under the FileInspector.

- View

  - ScrollView

    - ContainerView (if you want one or have one)

      - View
      - UIControl (if you have one)
      - THE CONTENTS OF YOUR VIEW.

You must however make a declaration of the scrollView in your header file:

```
   IBOutlet UIScrollView *yourScrollViewName;
```

In your main under viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
yourScrollViewName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[yourScrollViewName setScrollEnabled:YES];
[yourScrollViewName setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 ,554)]; //320 is the x which is the width. change this to make it horizontal. 
//554 is the Height this has to be larger that the screen size in order to have vertical scrolling.
[yourScrollViewName setPagingEnabled:NO];
}
```